# Google PageSpeed Insights says my website is heavy. Is external modals a solution?

Tags: javascript, ajax, optimization, bootstrap-modal, pagespeed

I am developing this one-page website for my office's portfolio and, to keep it clean, I am using bootstrap modal to hide some contents (pretty much images and descriptions). This is making the whole page heavy according to Google PageSpeed Insights. Looking for a solutions, I was thinking on loading all the modals as external html files using this:

```
www.jsfiddle.net/qp7NP/
```

I don't know if that would be the smartest solution for my case. I was concerning about SEO too. I read that AJAX somehow is used to load content dynamically, but I'm not familiar with AJAX at all. If any of you knows any solution for my case or can advice me on the page speed matter, I would be very grateful!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

AJAX really isn't as scary as it sounds, it is a great option for something like this as it allows you to load in massive amounts of conntent witha few lines of JavaScript, meaning a smaller initial load time regardless of additional content.

The example below demonstrates how content 'below the fold' (below the starting scroll position) can be loaded as HTML and inserted wherever necessary.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page Title.</h1>
    <p>This is the content which is on the screen at load</p>

    <!-- this is the div which will hold all content outside of view when the page loads -->
    <div id="below_fold"></div>

    <script>
    // get the content on once the page has loaded
    window.onload = function() {
      // set up http request object
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // tell http object what to do when response is recieved
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // if its all good then go ahead
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          // add content to div
          document.getElementById("below_fold").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
        // else we don't do anything, you could display an error or try again
      };
      // set file path for contents
      xhttp.open("GET", "below_fold_content_html.txt", true);
      // send request, xhttp.onreadystatechange will be called when completed
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(example above is an addaption of http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: Thank you very much, Charlie! I will take a look at it today!!